# ASP.NET MVC: Why the Account Model sample use MembershipProvider instead of just Membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I'm a little confused. In many tutorials, including some in MSDN and ASP.NET website, it's almost always about **Membership**. But when examining the AccountModel class that's created by default, it's about an objet called **_provider** of type **MembershipProvider**.

First, I wonder why they just don't use Membership instead of MembershipProvider? 
secondly (and most irritating), why when I try to use **_provider.GetAllUsers()**, I'm asked to provide also parameters stuff such as **pageindex**, **pagesize**, etc. But, when I use **Membership.GetAllUsers()**, I don't have to supply anything.

What the point of having both Membership and MembershipProvider with slightly different methods?

**EDIT**

Those are some of the documents I have used to learn how to use Membership. I'm talking about my books.

[ASP.NET tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs),

[4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx),

[An other 4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx),

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Thanks for helping

Comment: Testability! Didn't you read about that in the tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MembershipProvider` is an abstract class, meaning you can't create a new instance of it, rather, you must create your own custom class that inherits from it and then implement the functions.

Having a base class as a constructor means you can pass in any class that inherits from it. As others have said, this helps when you're testing. You can pass in a fake implementation or a mock of `MembershipProvider` to test all the functionality of your controller/class.

Comment: Thanks for your answers which help me to understand why the didn't just use Membership, but rather Membership.Provider.

Comment: But, why they present slightly different methods? For instance, why I need to supply params with Membership.Provider? while I don't have to if don't use it?

Comment: Can you clarify your comment?

Comment: I feel like the API has been modify. But, that's not really an issue. It's just annoying when you expect a method's signature to be and you get instead that. But, it works. For the rest, I understood that Membershipprovider is a abstract class aiming to ease the teastability.

Answer (score 2):

If you just use membership instead of a provider, you would have to supply a configuration file with a mock provider for your tests. In this way, you simply create a fake membership provider and use it when you create the MembershipService instance. Membership is just a wrapper around the default MembershipProvider. So as @bzlm said, it is more testable to use the provider rather than the Membership static class.